# How to override Phonegap webview's methods?

Tags: android, cordova, methods, webview, overriding

I have an Android application with one activity extend from DroidGap. Now I want to detect whether webview has reached the end or not, so I must override appView's `onScrollChanged` method (the instance name of webview in DroidGap is called appView). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view that extends CordovaWebView and you can override parts of DroidGap to use this instead of the baked in initialization code.  However, once you start messing with the view, you probably want to start investigating using your own Android activity instead of DroidGap.